# Android studio CMake does not link the prebuilt library to the main .so file

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I eventually cross-compiled a [capstone library](https://github.com/aquynh/capstone) for android, but now I am having trouble linking it with my main `.so` library(native-lib).
I followed the steps shown in the [official web site](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake).

My CMakeList.txt is as below.

```
# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build your native library.
# This ensures that a certain set of CMake features is available to
# your build.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Specifies a library name, specifies whether the library is STATIC or
# SHARED, and provides relative paths to the source code. You can
# define multiple libraries by adding multiple add.library() commands,
# and CMake builds them for you. When you build your app, Gradle
# automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Specifies the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

find_library( # Defines the name of the path variable that stores the
              # location of the NDK library.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # CMake needs to locate.
              log )

# Links your native library against one or more other native libraries.
#target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
#                       native-lib
#
#                      # Links the log library to the target library.
#                       ${log-lib} )

add_library( capstone
        SHARED
        IMPORTED )

set_target_properties( # Specifies the target library.
        capstone

        # Specifies the parameter you want to define.
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION

        # Provides the path to the library you want to import.
        C:/Users/82102/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Disassembler/capstone/${ANDROID_ABI}/libcapstone.so.5 )

target_link_libraries( native-lib capstone ${log-lib} ) #app-glue


include_directories( capstone/include/ )
```

The APK built has `native-lib.so`, but does not have 'libcapstone.so`or`libcapstone.so.5`. So when I launch the APK, the error below happens.

```
2019-08-22 14:21:01.340 6122-6122/com.kyhsgeekcode.disassembler E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.kyhsgeekcode.disassembler, PID: 6122
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libcapstone.so.5" not found
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1016)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
        at com.kyhsgeekcode.disassembler.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:169)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
```

I tried adding a `jniLibs` directory in the folder and adding the libcapstone.so.5, but the APK built still does not contain libcapstone.so.(5) and the same error happens.

How should I edit my CMakeList.txt to correctly link a custom prebuilt library to a main shared library?(native-lib.so)

Comment: IIRC versioned dynamic libraries are not supported by android, try renaming `libcapstone.so.5` to `libcapstone.so` before the Android Studio build.

Comment: @RichardCritten post an answer so it can be marked as correct :)

Comment: @DanAlbert it was an IIRC, a bit of a guess and I can't test it myself.  If someone else can verify it then an answer can be posted.  Without testing it I don't feel confident enough.

Comment: CMake is different from ndk-build in that it does not copy the prebuilt shared libs to be packed into the APK or bundle. We have to add `C:/Users/82102/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Disassembler/capstone/`
` to **jniLibs**. Still, versioned name will not be supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my CMakeLists.txt to link the capstone as a static library.

```
# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build your native library.
# This ensures that a certain set of CMake features is available to
# your build.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Specifies a library name, specifies whether the library is STATIC or
# SHARED, and provides relative paths to the source code. You can
# define multiple libraries by adding multiple add.library() commands,
# and CMake builds them for you. When you build your app, Gradle
# automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Specifies the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

find_library( # Defines the name of the path variable that stores the
              # location of the NDK library.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # CMake needs to locate.
              log )

# Links your native library against one or more other native libraries.
#target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
#                       native-lib
#
#                      # Links the log library to the target library.
#                       ${log-lib} )

#add_library( capstone
#        SHARED
#        IMPORTED )

#set_target_properties( # Specifies the target library.
#        capstone
#
#        # Specifies the parameter you want to define.
#        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION#
#
#        # Provides the path to the library you want to import.
#        C:/Users/82102/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Disassembler/capstone/${ANDROID_ABI}/libcapstone. )

target_link_libraries( native-lib C:/Users/82102/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Disassembler/capstone/${ANDROID_ABI}/libcapstone.a ${log-lib} ) #app-glue


include_directories( capstone/include/ )
```

Hopefully, it worked!